Kernel and Image of polynomial differentiation linear transformation
Let
$$D:P_5 \to P_5 \\
 p \mapsto -p''$$
Find the kernel and image of the linear transformation.
I've been given the answers, but i don't understand how they've got there
$$ Im(D) = span(\{1,t,-t^2,t^3\}) \\
 Ker(D) = span(\{321, 123t\}) $$
This is what i've got so far,
$ \text{Let} \ \beta \ \text{be the standard basis of} \ P_5, \text{so} \ \beta=\{1,t,t^2,t^3,t^4,t^5\} \ \text{and} \ D(\beta)=\{0,0,-2,-6t,-12t^2,-20t^3\}$
$Im(D)=span(D(\beta)) \Rightarrow Im(D) = span(\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}) \ \text{since the standard basis for} \ P_3 \ \text{is} \ \{1,t,t^2,t^3\} $
$Ker(D) = \{p \in P_5 | D(p)=0\} \\
 \text{since} \ D(1) = 0 \ \text{and} \ D(t) = 0 \ \text{then} \ D(a_0) = 0 \ \text{and} \  D(a_1t) = 0 \ \forall a_o,a_1 \in R \\
\text{thus} \ Ker(D)=span\{1,t\}$
my answers aren't correct but i have no idea where i'm going wrong

Your answers are correct

so are my professors answers wrong?

No, both answers are equal. Try proving that both descrriptions yield the same spaces.

I don't understand what $321$ and $321t$ mean here.  Perhaps someone was just making the point that you don't need to use "simple" basis vectors.  You could, for instance, use ${\sqrt 2 t +\pi, -\sqrt {11}t-13}$ as your two basis vectors.

i'm not sure what 321 or 123t mean either, i'm guessing they are placeholders of sorts as you suggested, but also their kernel is different to mine, they have $-t^2$ where i have $t^2$

It's only the span that matters.  You should convince yourself that those stray constants don't change the span.
